# Is it possible in Java to avoid using assignments?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Is it possible in Java to avoid using assignments? In lisp it's fairly easy to confine would-be assignments to iteration via tail recursion, mapping - and data modification via binding - but Java doesn't really do any tail-recursion optimization. Are there ways in java to bind to data without assignment?

Comment: Bind data to what? What tag body are you talking about? This is too vague to answer at the moment.

Comment: Since LISP is a functional language and Java is an imperative language, the language isn't designed to handle this.  Also, whether Java does tail-recursion optimization is mostly dependent on the JVM implementation; I'd be surprised if HotSpot et al didn't do this.

Comment: I like the "non-originating tag body" part.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in Java?  Scala handles not using assignments well and runs on the JVM.

Comment: Whatever your question really is, you should be able to answer it easily yourself: all you need to know is the very basics of Java.

Comment: @templatetypedef There is no bytecode for a TCO and that's a show-stopper. If you write TCO code, no "maybe" about it can be tolerated.

Comment: I'm new to java.  I'm simply trying to understand if it is possible to write code in java without using ANY assignments.

Comment: The simplest way to do iteration in Java is to use iteration, and for Java, in 90+% of cases iteration is faster if not simpler than using recursion.  Assignments have next to no cost for compiled code and the JIT can eliminate them when it can.

Comment: I assume the need to avoid assignments is a matter of taste rather than say performance as Scala is generally slower than Java unless you are careful.

Comment: Nope.  It has to do with writing bug-less code.

Comment: Also, why was this thread closed?  It seems a perfectly reasonable question. It's not like I don't understand that Java wasn't built to not use assignments. I simply wanted to know if it could be done and if it could be done without calling another method with anything more than a simply transfer of control of the program. Geez.  I lost all my rep points on this.

Comment: What is the principal difference between `setq` and assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own bunch of classes to simulate `Lisp`, but you can't simulate it with java itself.